# What are some good resources for learning bit shifting?

Tags: bit, bit-shift

I'd like to add some real bit shifting skills to my toolkit. What are some good resources?

I'm aiming for fluency; I want to be able to think in bit shifting patterns the same way I think in memos or maps or folds or recursion.

Comment: @Socowi Thanks! Got started on this last night. Seems very nice. Would you consider making your comment and answer, so I can approve it?

Comment: Glad to hear that and thank you for the offer. I wrote a comment instead of an answer, because the Stackoverflow guidelines specifically list "Recommendation for books, ..." as off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "standard" resources for bit manipulations are

- the website [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html) by Sean Eron Anderson, and
- the book *Hacker's Delight* by Henry S. Warren Jr. (full, but malformed scan available [here](https://doc.lagout.org/security/Hackers%20Delight.pdf)).

Those won't teach you directly how to come up with solutions on your own, but this is normal for learning. Look at the examples there and learn from them.